# marklogic 8.0 xdmp:http-get

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a question about the implementation of API:

```
xdmp:http-get()
```

1. Does it use something like java httpConnectionPool? it means that how long the marklogic server hold the httpconnection, and the httpconnection will be reuse or release immediately.
2. If do have the httpConnectionPool mechanism, how can I config this pool and the maximum 
   Concurrent number?(the maxium request support/per second)

Comment: Are you calling `xdmp:http-get` multiple times within one request to MarkLogic, or are you hoping that a connection will be preserved across multiple requests?